# How to refactor switch statements in loop javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have lots of switch statements. These are may be more than 200. We are update the object according to conditions.

How can improve this script

```
function getJSONFormat(content) {
      const attrbutesArr = [];
      let attributes = content.attributes;
      for (let i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
        let attrElement = attributes[i];
        let attr_type = attrElement.trait_type;
        switch (attr_type) {
          case "Wings Female":
            attrElement.trait_type = "Wings";
            break;
          case "Wings Male":
            attrElement.trait_type = "Wings";
            break;
    
          case "Body Female Brown":
            attrElement.trait_type = "Body";
            break;
          case "Body Female Grey":
            attrElement.trait_type = "Body";
            break;
        }
      }
      let attrs = content.attributes;
      const deleteNodes = new Set(deleteNodesArr);
      let newAttributes = attrs.filter((obj) => !deleteNodes.has(obj.trait_type));
      content.attributes = newAttributes;
      return content;
    }
```

Please guide us.

Thanks

Comment: For one, your code isn't formatted properly. You need to explain better what the code does and what all the strings look like. With only the examples you give, it looks like you could just take the first word of each string.

Comment: @RoToRa Formatted code done please check

Comment: `may be more than 200 [switch statements]` Show me enough to bore me, to make me want a better approach. Are associations `attr_type` string ↔ `trait_type` subject to change?

Comment: @greybeard `attr_type` is string

Comment: The Code Review Community is quite different from Stack Overflow, we need to see as much code as possible to help you improve rather than a minimum amount of code to necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about to use Map?
You can save a lot of code by setting just key value list.

```javascript
  const m = new Map([
    ["Wings Female", "Wings"],
    ["Wings Male", "Wings"],
    ["Body Female Brown", "Body"],
    ["Body Female Grey", "Body"],
  ]);

  let attributes = content.attributes;
  for (let i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
    let attrElement = attributes[i];
    let attr_type = attrElement.trait_type;
    // Set value by attr_type or original value
    attrElement.trait_type = m.get(attr_type) || attrElement.trait_type;
  }
```